# Rails has_many nested form No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm getting the above error when I submit my nested form and I'm not sure how to fix it.  Here is some info.  The exact error is `No route matches [POST] "/vehicles/2/vehicle_records/new"`.  The strange thing is that route is present when I run rake routes I see the following entry

```
/vehicles/:vehicle_id/vehicle_records/new(.:format)
```

vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicle_records,  dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle_records
end
```

vehicle_record.rb

```
class VehicleRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

I want the ability to add a vehicle maintenance record linked from the vehicle show view.

views/vehicle/show.html.erb

```
<h3><b>Vehicle ID:</b> <%= @vehicle.id %></h3>

<p><b>Year:</b> <%= @vehicle.year %></p>

<p><b>Make:</b> <%= @vehicle.make %></p>
<p><b>Model:</b> <%= @vehicle.model %></p>
<p><b>Work Last Performed:</b> <%= @vehicle.make %></p>


<h2>Maintenance Record</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date Performed</th>
    <th>Mileage</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Work Performed</th>
  </tr>
  <% @vehicle.vehicle_records.each do |vr|%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= vr.date_performed %></td>
      <td><%= vr.mileage %></td>
      <td><%= vr.hours %></td>
      <td><%= vr.work_performed %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to "Add Maintenance Record", new_vehicle_vehicle_record_path(@vehicle) %>
```

I then link to the vehicle_record new form

views/vehicle_records/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :vehicle_record do |vr| %>
  <p>
    <%= vr.label :date_performed%><br />
    <%= vr.text_field :date_performed%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= vr.label :mileage%><br />
    <%= vr.text_field :mileage%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= vr.label :mileage%><br />
    <%= vr.text_field :mileage%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= vr.label :hours%><br />
    <%= vr.text_field :hours%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= vr.label :work_performed%><br />
    <%= vr.text_area :work_performed%>
  </p>

  <p><%= vr.submit "Create Record" %></p>
```

My vehicle records controller is as follows

vehicle_records_controller.rb

```
class VehicleRecordsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @vehicle_record = VehicleRecord.new
  end

  def create
    @vehicle_record = VehicleRecord.new(params[:vehicle_record])

    if @vehicle_record.save
      redirect_to vehicles_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Not Saved"
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :vehicles do
  resources :vehicle_records
end
```

Comment: add your routes.rb file to question, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update: w/o nested forms***

So I hear you only want to only edit the `vehicle_report` without touching the `vehicle`. Since you already have your `vehicle_report` as nested resource, you can modify your controller as follows:

```
class VehicleRecordController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find params[:vehicle_id]
    @vehicle_record = @vehicle.vehicle_records.build
  end

  ...
end
```

and the content of `create` method is fairly easy. Then you have to change your form to:

```
<%= form_for @vehicle_record do |v| %>
  ...
  <%= # vehicle record attributes %>
  ...
  <%= v.submit "Submit" %>
```

And you are good to go!

***Original answer: w/ nested forms***

First of all, I don't see you using any nested forms. Second, I don't see how your `vehicle_record` form gets to know to which `vehicle` it actually belongs (see your controller). In my opinion the simplest way would be to allow adding and removing of `vehicle_records` directly in `vehicles/:id/edit` or `vehicles/new` using [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms):

```
<%= form_for @vehicle do |v| %>
  ...
  <%= # vehicle attributes here %>
  ...
  <%= v.fields_for :vehicle_records do |vr| %>
    ...
    <%= # vehicle record attributes %>
    ...
  <%= v.submit "Submit" %>
```

For existing `vehicles` the `fields_for` will render list of all existing `vehicle_records` and for new ones your can have the following code in your controller to make `fields_for` render for example three empty `vehicle_records`:

```
class VehicleController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @vehicle = new Vehicle
    3.times { @vehicle.vehicle_records.build }
  end

  ...
end
```

If you want to always have a number of free `vehicle_records` every time you edit an existing `vehicle` you can use a similar approach for your edit and reuse the aforementioned form:

```
class VehicleController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def edit
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find params[:id]
    # Add one blank vehicle record to existing ones
    # This is also rendered by fields_for
    @vehicle.vehicle_records.build
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: I believe my thought was that since a vehicle would not need to be updated once created, that adding maintenance record entries would be better located in the show view for the vehicle.  Nested forms also has the drawback of opening every vehicle record for edit introducing potential user error. That's why I wanted to put the vehicle record form in its own view so I would only be creating/editing one entry at a time.

Comment: Well what your code does is simply creating records which belong to no vehicle! And if you want only to edit the records you really don't need to have records as nested resources of the vehicles.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps a lot.  Was able to pass vehicle id to records controller to create the record without nested forms.  I've used nested resources before but I guess I didn't fully understand its specific use

Comment: @ctilley79 I suggest a new solution for you. Hope it finally solves your problem.